# Simple expression parsing throws a TypeError referencing 'AssumptionKeys'

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to get sympy to calculate the result of what should be a simple expression with three substitutions, but I'm coming up against an error I've not encountered before.

```
>>> from sympy import sympify, symbols 
>>> input_str = '100*Q+10*R+5*S+0.6*T'
>>> Q,R,S,T = symbols('Q R S T')
```

The above code works fine, but when I run the string though sympify, I get the following error:

```
>>> sympify(input_str)
ValueError: Error from parse_expr with transformed code: "Integer (100 )*Q +Integer (10 )*Symbol ('R' )+Integer (5 )*S +Float ('0.6' )*Symbol ('T' )"


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "...ipykernel_5652\212826607.py", line 1, in <cell line: 1>
    sympify(input_str)

  File "...\Python\Python310\site-packages\sympy\core\sympify.py", line 496, in sympify
    expr = parse_expr(a, local_dict=locals, transformations=transformations, evaluate=evaluate)

  File "...\Python\Python310\site-packages\sympy\parsing\sympy_parser.py", line 1101, in parse_expr
    raise e from ValueError(f"Error from parse_expr with transformed code: {code!r}")

  File "...\Python\Python310\site-packages\sympy\parsing\sympy_parser.py", line 1092, in parse_expr
    rv = eval_expr(code, local_dict, global_dict)

  File "...Python\Python310\site-packages\sympy\parsing\sympy_parser.py", line 907, in eval_expr
    expr = eval(

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Integer' and 'AssumptionKeys'
```

What on earth could be causing this error with such a simple expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Q` is one of the single letter objects that are not symbols in SymPy. During sympification, functions (and some single-letter objects) are parsed as their SymPy definition. When used improperly (as in this case) it raises an error, just like parsing "cos + x" or "beta + alpha" would raise, the latter because `beta` is a function expecting 1 or 2 arguments. (For the record, all such single letter symbols are in "QOSINE"; any other letters will `sympify` without issues.) There is an issue opened for this [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/24397). One of the ways to deal with this is to pass the clashing symbols as `locals` during sympification as suggested in the `abc.py` file:

> The module also defines some special names to help detect which names clash
> with the default SymPy namespace.
> `_clash1` defines all the single letter variables that clash with
> SymPy objects; `_clash2` defines the multi-letter clashing symbols;
> and `_clash` is the union of both. These can be passed for `locals`
> during sympification if one desires Symbols rather than the non-Symbol
> objects for those names.

```py
>>> from sympy import S
>>> from sympy.abc import _clash1, _clash2, _clash
>>> S("Q & C", locals=_clash1)
C & Q
>>> S('pi(x)', locals=_clash2)
pi(x)
>>> S('pi(C, Q)', locals=_clash)
pi(C, Q)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the character `"Q"`. Once it gets sympified it will represent `AssumptionKeys`. You probably need to use something like this, in which we ask `sympify` to replace the character `"Q"` with symbol `Q`:

```py
Q = symbols("Q")
sympify('100*Q+10*R+5*s+0.6*T', locals={"Q": Q})
```

Answer (score 2):

Capital letters are reserved for other purposes in SymPy eg the singleton class is accessible as S while Q is a property of Sympy. Replace your capital letters by lower case letters and it should work:

```
    q, r, s, t = symbols('Q R S T')  
    input_str = '100*q +10*r + 5*s +0.6*t'  
    sympify(input_str)
```